# Mostrar en pantalla valores escogidos en dropdownbutton

Tags: flutter

Tengo dos dropdownbutton en una página, y quiero mostrar los valores que escogí en la pantalla. Los dropdown funcionan bien, pero no puedo mostrar sus valores en la parte de abajo. Tomé como base el ejemplo de dropdown que viene en la documentación de Flutter.

Lo que hago es lo siguiente: primero creo dos widgets *combouno* y *combodos* que son los dos dropdown, en ambos las personas escogen colores, y luego creo dos widgets que me mostrarian los ítems que escogí, pero no logro hacerlo.

Estos valores los necesito porque después voy a poner un condicional que combine los dos colores, ejemplo: cyan y amarillo, dan un nuevo color que es el verde.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Hometest());

class Hometest extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hometest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Test Combo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ComboUno(),
            ComboDos(),
            TextUno(),
            TextDos(),
                contenedorColorUno(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    //);
  }
}


//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::inicio widgets combos
class ComboUno extends StatefulWidget {
  const ComboUno({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ComboUno> createState() => _ComboUnoState();
}

class _ComboUnoState extends State<ComboUno> {
  String dropdownValue1 = 'cyan';
  String? nuevoColor;
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue1,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          elevation: 16,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
             nuevoColor = newValue!;
            });
          },
          items: <String>['cyan', 'yellow', 'red']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        contenedorColorUno(),
]);
      }
  }


//:::::inicio combodos
class ComboDos extends StatefulWidget {
  const ComboDos({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ComboDos> createState() => _ComboDosState();
}

class _ComboDosState extends State<ComboDos> {
  String dropdownValue2 = 'red';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue2,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue2 = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['red', 'cyan', 'yellow']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::fin widgets combos

class TextUno extends StatefulWidget {
  String? color;
  TextUno({Key? key, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TextUnoState createState() => TextUnoState();
}

class TextUnoState extends State<TextUno> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('First Color is: ${widget.color}');
  }
}

class TextDos extends StatefulWidget {
  String? color;
  TextDos({Key? key, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TextDosState createState() => TextDosState();
}

class TextDosState extends State<TextDos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Second Color is: ${widget.color}');
  }
}



Widget contenedorColorUno() {
  //var nuevoColor;
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Text('Mi color es: $nuevoColor'),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola podrías crear una nueva `variable de clase` tanto en `combo1` como en `combo2`:

```
String? nuevoColor;
```

Y ahora en el `onchange` le asignas el nuevo color a la nueva variable:

```
onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      nuevoColor = newValue!
    });
  },
```

Y si quieres que automaticamente te navegue a la otra pantalla podrías aplicar:

```
    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          nuevoColor = newValue!
        });
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
        (builder) => TextUno(color: nuevoColor),);
      },
```

Para hacer lo que está arriba, tienes que cambiar el estado de la clase `TextUno` a StatefulWidget, y asignarle un parametro de nombre `color`:

```
  class TextUno extends StatefulWidget {
   String? color;
   TextUno({Key? key, this.color}) : super(key: key);
   
   @override
   TextUnoState createState() => TextUnoState();
 }

class TextUnoState extends State<TextUno>{
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('First Color is: ${widget.color}');
  }
```

}
//--ACTUALIZACION--//
Si lo que quieres es presentar el nuevo color en la misma pantalla, simplemente juega con la variable que ya tienes creada `nuevoColor`:

```
    Widget contenedorColorUno(){
   return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Text('Mi color es: $nuevoColor'),
);
}
```

Y este widget lo agregas en tu clase:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue1,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          elevation: 16,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
             nuevoColor = newValue!
            });
          },
          items: <String>['cyan', 'yellow', 'red']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
        contenedorColorUno(),
]);
      }
```

En el `onchange` tienes que quitar el Navigator, para que no te navegue a la nueva pagina

Comment: Gracias jonathan por tu comentario, efectivamente puedo ver en una nueva pantalla sin formato el texto 'First Color is Cyan' o el color que escogí, podría ser que apareciera en la misma pantalla, incluyendo un botón?

Comment: Acabé de hacer una actualización al final de la respuesta para que te guíes, si lo que quieres hacer con el boton es pasarlo como parametro a otra clase, tienes que hacer lo mismo del Navigator y con eso ya estaría, espero y la respuesta te haya servido

Comment: hola Jonathan, muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, realice los cambios que me recomiendas, pero en el Widget contenedorColorUno que puse al final, me muestra error: Undefined name nuevoColor, actualice el código, con los cambios.

Comment: En que pantalla quieres presentar el color?

Comment: en la misma pantalla, el va a tomar el color uno, y el color dos, y con unos condicionales, (if) va a preparar el color tres, lo que quiero al final es sacar ese valor que se escoge, a una variable, para poderlo usar, gracias.

Comment: ahh, pero lo que yo te estaba enseñando son variables temporales, te sugiero que crees una pequeña base de datos con sqflite y luego almacenes esos valores, para luego llamarlos por medio de un FutureBuilder, aquí te dejo la documentación de flutter para que te guíes: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Comment: Parece entonces que solo puedo tener ese valor dentro del dropdownbotton, y no puedo sacarlo de alli a una variable, para usar en el resto del código sin utilizar la base de datos. gracias Jonathan por tu respuesta,

Comment: Hola he encontrado una solución sin usar sqlite: sacando el valor de la lista en otro widget: 
  Widget _crearColor() {
    return ListTile(
      trailing: Text(_opcionSeleccionada),
    );
  }
}